# issue with position relative on a tag

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-position

```
<style>
    span{
        position:relative;
        left:100px;
    }
</style>
<a href="newpage.html"><span>some text</span></a>
```

as pic below show, the text and the link shift to right 100px,
however, i can still able to  click on the empty space where the text was before positioning.
how do i fix that without using position absolute? 
Thanks for your time and your help, you guys are the best.

[image]

Comment: Nice screenshot! You know, you can use `prt sc` next time

Comment: i don't know how to print screen on mac to show the hand icon.

Comment: Use `Command-Shift-3` then

Comment: cmd shift-3 only printscreen, but won't show the arrow, or the hand icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes your `span` go 100px right, but the `a` element wraps both `some text` and the 100px whitespace.

To fix that, you should put a `margin` to your `a` element, like so:

```
<style>
    a{
        position:relative;
        left:100px;
    }
    // OR
    a{
        margin-left:100px;
    }
</style>
```